# Different result when hitting breakpoints, using DLL and C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

I´m trying to develop a small game for school using C/C++ and a DLL that I made and linked implicitly. So far so good. 
Now I'm testing some functions and I'm getting different results when I run all code at once or if I put a breakpoint to stop the code.

I'll show some code and I'll try to explain the best I can.

```
struct powerup get_powerup() {
struct powerup aux {};

srand(time(nullptr));
int r = rand() % 100 + 1; // random number between 1 and 100

if (r <= 60) //common
    aux.occurrence = common;
else if (r > 60 && r < 90) //rare
    aux.occurrence = uncommon;
else if (r >= 90) //very rare
    aux.occurrence = rare;

switch (aux.occurrence)
{
case common:
    r = rand() % 2 + 1;

    if (r == 1)
        aux = set_powerup(shield);
    if (r == 2)
        aux = set_powerup(enemy_boost);
    break;
case uncommon:
    r = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if (r == 1)
        aux = set_powerup(ice);
    if (r == 2)
        aux = set_powerup(battery);
    else if (r == 3)
        aux = set_powerup(alchool);
    break;
case rare:
    r = rand() % 2 + 1;

    if (r == 1)
        aux = set_powerup(life);
    if (r == 2)
        aux = set_powerup(noclip);
    break;
}

return aux;
}
```

This is the function I'm testing, very simple and works fine.

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) {
#ifdef UNICODE
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_WTEXT);
#endif
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    const struct powerup ajux = get_powerup();

    _tprintf(TEXT("power up: %hs\n"), powerup_type_string[ajux.type]);
}

system("Pause");

return 0;
}
```

This is my main code.
Now the odd part, at least for me. And before you say "its because it's a random generator", hold on for a moment.

When running the code all at once, I get the same result every time:

```
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
```

But if put a breakpoint someone in the for loop, I get the expected result:

```
power up: Shield
power up: Battery
power up: Ice
power up: Alchool
power up: Alchool
power up: Battery
power up: No Clip
power up: Life
power up: Enemy Boost
power up: Enemy Boost
```

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Please copy-paste the output as text, instead of providing screenshots of it.

Comment: c and c++ are different languages, there is no c/c++ language. It seems like this is c. It's important to specify for which language you are asking since answers in c++ and answers in c are frequently very different.

Comment: It's unclear what is this code supposed to do, what is wrong with the output and how should it look like?

Comment: `nullptr` is only available since C++11

Comment: The dll was written in C++, the main program in C. The first output should be similar to the second. The second output is the "good one". I can only achieve that if I have breakpoints on the code, and that makes no sense for me. Every iteration of the for loop should give a different output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's because of the random generator.

You are calling `srand(time(nullptr))` inside `get_powerup`.
That means the random number generator is seeded from the current time on every call, and because `time` is on a second granularity, will appear to return the same value when you run the code.

The idea of `srand` is to be called only once during application startup to seed the PRNG. Move it to the beginning of the `main` function.

Comment: Spot on my friend, thanks. Thought that it would trigger a new time on every call

Comment: As an alternative; @TonyMendes there are better rand functions in c++ if you can move it to your dll.